# Trying to set background image for UITableView but there is a delay in loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set a background image for my UITableView using

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableback.png"]];
```

I am  having some problems with it. If i place it in the `viewDidLoad` method it won't appear. If I place it in the `viewDidAppear` method it works but there is a delay before it appears. Could someone give me a pointer on the best way to go about this please? Thank!

Comment: Set background color of table view to [UIColor clearColor] and add imageView behind the tableView .Not what you asked for but will solve your problem differently.

Comment: how do I add the imageView behind the tableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you have correctly set the layout constraints of a tableView  this would do this code in viewDidLoad should do the trick.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
**imgView.frame = self.tableView.frame;**

[self.view insertSubview:imgView belowSubview:self.tableView];
```

*There's also possibility that ur cells view in the tableView is obstructing the tableview's backgroundView. In that case test by setting the background color of cell also to [UIColor clearColor]*

Comment: I'm getting a strange black rectangle in the background now

Comment: The image you are loading is black? also try changing the  edit and make sure cell's content view's background is also clear.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `backgroundView` property in `viewWillAppear` method.